# cx_freeze compiled python - importError

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I am trying to run compiled Python executable (python 3.5 win-64) with cx_freeze from different computers and I have faced such problem

```
ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']
```

The problem is that it works on my computer where I created the script, but on others it refers to my computer as a library path.

But why? I thought that compiled python script contains all libs inside itself.

I tried to include numpy into packages list within setup.py

```
packages = ['scipy', 'pandas', 'sklearn', 'dill', 'getpass', 'numpy']
```

But the error is still there.